# How to make an OR operation for middleware in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware

```
Laravel 5.7
PHP 7.2.10
```

For example my route is

```
Route::middleware('auth', 'emailVerified', 'phoneVerified', 'flatTenant|flatResident|flatMember')->get('apartments/{apartment}/flats/{flat}/guests/{guest}', 'Api\GuestController@show')->name('Api.guests.show');
```

I want it to work like any of flatTenant, flatResident and flatMember this should allow the request, what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Why not create one middleware `flat` and check there for tenants or residents or members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to make or operation inside route. Instead you can make your own authentication which will check whether or not the current user is any of flatTenant, flatResident and flatMember.

For example you can register a middleware named 'flatChecker'.

Then inside that middleware your code can be something like this,

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->isFlatTenant || Auth::user()->isFlatResident || Auth::user()->isFlatMember) //put your own condition to check  here
        {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect('/home'); //if they are not, then redirect them to somewhere else
    }
```

For more information on middleware check this [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware).